# window.scrollY coverage in jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-testing

I want to test below snippet in jest .Anyone can help me to do this
`

```
 const controlNavbar = useCallback(() => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      if (window.scrollY > lastScrollY) {
        setScrollUp(false)
      }
      if (window.scrollY < lastScrollY) {
        setScrollUp(true)
      }
      setLastScrollY(window.scrollY)
    }
  }, [lastScrollY])
```

`

I want to pass test coverage but it shows that I didn't cover this piece of code

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Tried alot of solution nothing worked so far